# How to collapse the section when user click on the header of the section in UITableView?

Tags: iphone

IS there an easier way to animate the table view. All the rows in my table view change when the user clicks the tab on header of the section of the table view.

Comment: what kind of animation do you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use,

`[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section]
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`